# Why is Orthorectify button not active in Image Analysis Windows of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, orthophoto

[image: Ortho button not active]

I wanted to Ortho rectify GeoEye HR imagery using existing RPC and IFSAR DTM in Image Analysis. According to ArcGIS Resource center http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/using_the_Orthorectify_button/009t000000mv000000/ the button is automatically active if the imagery has RPC file. In my case the ortho button was not active although my Imagery has RPC file.

Comment: All of your image analysis options are grayed out. Did you make sure to click and highlight the layer in the list in your Image Analysis window?

Comment: Thanks. I missed out that step. I already click and highlight on the layer but still the Orthorectify button does not active. Any other step i missed?

Comment: Thank you very much. Still cannot find the way to do Orthorectification for GeoEye1 in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to select both layers, the image and the DEM used for orthorectification. And the image has to have a RPC or RPB file with the same name.